# HGLOBAL return values in Crystal Reports UFL's UF5SaveState and UF5RestoreState

Tags: c++, windows, crystal-reports

Using C++ to write a UFL for Crystal reports I get the option to implement the UF5SaveState and UF5RestoreState functions, which you don't get with the COM interface resulting in the problems that these functions exist to solve.

The UF5SaveState function that I must implement has this signature:-

```
HGLOBAL __stdcall UF5SaveState (UFTInt32u jobId)
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to form the HGLOBAL it's expected to return.

The docs say only this:-

> UF5SaveState This procedure must be
>   implemented only if your UFL has a
>   function with side  effects **[It does indeed]**. It is
>   called by Crystal Reports to obtain
>   the state from the UFL at a  given
>   point. The Crystal Reports job number
>   is passed to the function. The 
>   function returns the UFL state binary
>   stream in the second parameter, and 
>   returns the size of the state in the
>   third parameter.

I am most confused, not least because it talks about returning things in second and even third parameters. I'm not really a windows person so to me HGLOBAL looks a lot like a void pointer and so I expect it is more meaningful to windows people. I've tried passing back the results of a GlobalAlloc, tried creating a stream from it (CreateStreamOnHGlobal) and passing that back, tried just a char *, all result in an un-handled exception:-

> Unhandled exception at 0x7c92a978
>   (ntdll.dll) in crw32.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location
>   0x00030fa4.

I have no doubt that this is because it's expecting something else, but what...

A chunk of code, that doesn't work just to help y'all get going:-

```
HGLOBAL __stdcall UF5SaveState (UFTInt32u jobId)
{
 ULONG bytesWritten;
 HGLOBAL result = GlobalAlloc(GHND, 2048);
 LPSTREAM stream = LPSTREAM(); 
 CreateStreamOnHGlobal(result, false, &stream);
 stream->Write("ABC", 3, &bytesWritten);
 stream->Release();

 return result;
}
```

So, imagine I want to save a state that is just the three characters "ABC" zero terminator optional, how do I do it?

Comment: I'm glad it's foxed other people too...

Comment: Someone must have an idea? Is the question not clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom CR function a million years ago.  The uffuncs.h header file contained these definitions:

```
HGLOBAL CR_EXPORT UF5SaveState (UFTInt32u jobId);
UFError CR_EXPORT UF5RestoreState (UFTInt32u jobId,
                                   HGLOBAL savedState);
```

The documentation you found is compelling though, a HGLOBAL isn't nearly good enough to persist inside a report.  It's a pointer, that's not going to restore properly when the report is loaded again in another session.  Those mysterious extra arguments would allow for this.

This header file has a 1997 timestamp.  I can only recommend you try to find a more up to date version of the uffuncs.h header file.  Wherever it might be, I don't remember where I got it from.  The web site docs and links are totally inadequate.  Pretty typical CR lossage, I resolved to never use CR again after the misery I went through.

Comment: How I wish I had the option of ditching it completely. My problem is how to form whatever it is I am supposed to return via the HGLOBAL.

Comment: Oh, the file dates are about right. It's not changed an up-to-date CR does call the funcs ok.

Comment: The docs further suggest that the HGLOBAL should point to data that can be saved along with the report if necessary i.e. serialized. I don't need that level of persistence, just for the lifetime of the report run is enough for me.

Comment: Come to think of it, it *can* recover the size of the memory allocation with GlobalSize().  Watch out for some kind of macro in your code that redefs GlobalAlloc().  Verify that GlobalSize() returns the right value.  Also compare the address you get from GlobalLock() with the crash address to see if this at all related to your code.

Comment: The crash address doesn't resemble any of the addresses associated with the GlobalAlloc thing. I'll see what GlobalSize gives me. The code is very simple at this stage GlobalAlloc isn't redefined.

Comment: GlobalSize returns the size allocated with GlobalAlloc as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The common place HGLOBAL memory handles are still used is when setting the Windows clipboard. Crystal Reports is probably expecting exactly the same type of handle as you would use for that.

Here is the relevant code for creating an HGLOBAL with "ABC" in it:

```
const char *szInput = "ABC";
size_t cchBufLen = strlen(szInput) + 1; // +1 for the null-terminator.
size_t cbBufSize = cchBufLen * sizeof(char); // Len==Size, but wouldn't if you were using wchar_t instead of char.

bool bSuccess = false;
HGLOBAL hGlobalClipMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GHND, cbBufSize);

if (hGlobalClipMem != NULL)
{
    // Since the "GHND" flags include GMEM_MOVEABLE we must use GlobalLock to
    // get a pointer to the buffer, and later GlobalFree to get back to normal.
    char *pGlobalBuffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>( ::GlobalLock(hGlobalClipMem) );

    if (pGlobalBuffer != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(pGlobalBuffer, szInput);
        bSuccess = true; // Set false if anything fails here, so you clean-up.

        ::GlobalUnlock(hGlobalClipMem); // You unlock the hGlobal, not the pointer that came out of GlobalLock.
    }

    // Error-handling path.
    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        ::GlobalFree(hGlobalClipMem);
        hGlobalClipMem = NULL;
    }
}

return hGlobalClipMem; // Returns NULL on failure.
```

Comment: Nice try and tidier than my attempts, I still get the exception though.

Comment: In the GlobalAlloc call, instead of GHND, try using GPTR. (The GlobalLock/GlobalUnlock calls then become no-ops and could be removed, but can also be left in for easier testing.) If that still causes the crash I'd say the problem is somewhere else; e.g. what data format/structure is being passed back, rather than how it is being passed; or even a corrupt stack etc. that just happens to cause a crash here (but that's less likely). BTW, is your code running within the same process as what receives the data?

Comment: Swapping for GPTR gives me the slightly different exception:- Unhandled exception at 0x0012f38e in crw32.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction. I also think the problem is in the structure being passed but I don't have any info on what it's supposed to be.

Comment: It's all in the same process.